Density property between $L^1$ and $H^1$
I would like to know if the following property is true

Given the sobolev space $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and the Lebesgue space $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, is is true that $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)\cap H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is dense in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$?


Do you mean $L^1(\Bbb R^d)\cap H^1(\Bbb R^d)$? If so note that both spaces contain e.g. $C_c^\infty(\Bbb R^d)$
